Error connecting Salesforce Data Cloud to Databricks: CANNOT_VALIDATE_CONNECTION and INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE.CONNECTION_TYPE_NOT_ENABLED
I'm following the instructions in the documentation to set up a connection from our Salesforce Data Cloud app to Databricks.
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/query-federation/salesforce-data-cloud
In Catalog Explorer, I select Salesforce Data Cloud as the connection type and enter my client_id, client_secret, and the following scopes for the connection in Databricks: cdp_api api cdp_query_api refresh_token offline_access
When I test the connection, I see the following error:
CANNOT_VALIDATE_CONNECTION] Validation of UNKNOWN_CONNECTION_TYPE connection is not supported. Please contact Databricks support for alternative solutions, or set "spark.databricks.testConnectionBeforeCreation" to "false" to skip connection testing before creating a connection object. SQLSTATE: 08000, data: {"type":"baseError","stackFrames":["org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: [CANNOT_VALIDATE_CONNECTION] Validation of UNKNOWN_CONNECTION_TYPE connection is not supported. Please contact Databricks support for alternative solutions, or set \"spark.databricks.testConnectionBeforeCreation\" to \"false\" to skip connection testing before creating a connection object. SQLSTATE: 08000\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotValidateConnectionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1211)


I've also tried the SQL instructions from the section just below the Catalog Explorer documentation here:
Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/query-federation/salesforce-data-cloud#sql
I got the code from the URL and entered it in the SQL statement below:
CREATE CONNECTION sf_test TYPE SALESFORCE OPTIONS ( client_id 'blahblah', client_secret 'blahblah', pkce_verifier 'blahblah', authorization_code 'blahblah', oauth_redirect_uri "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success", oauth_scope "api refresh_token cdp_profile_api cdp_query_api", is_sandbox "false" );
When I run this, the TYPE SALESFORCE in the query above shows this error:
ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE.CONNECTION_TYPE_NOT_ENABLED] Connection type 'SALESFORCE' is not enabled. Please enable the connection to use it.

But if I use the TYPE from their instructions (salesforce_data_cloud), I see this error:
Cannot create connection of type 'salesforce_data_cloud'. Supported connection types: GA4_RAW_DATA, BIGQUERY, POSTGRESQL, WORKDAY_RAAS, REDSHIFT, SNOWFLAKE, MYSQL, SQLDW, SQLSERVER, FABRIC, SERVICENOW, NETSUITE, DATABRICKS, SALESFORCE. SQLSTATE: 42000

Any help would be appreciated!

is your workspace unity catalog enabled?

as per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/lakeflow-connect/salesforce/salesforce-ingestion/
You are following all the steps invloved in creating connection with salesforce.
You need to once check databricks to create case for lakeflow.

Yes, Unity Catalog is enabled in my workspace @JayashankarGS

@DileepRajNarayanThumula - so this is somethign additional that databricks needs to setup in our unity catalog? Is there documentation showing this?
